# Verify Heegaard diagrams are $S^3$

Tags: low-dimensional-topology

The Heegaard diagrams presented represent S^3, the 3 sphere. I would like to see how this is true. My understanding is that S^3 is the genus 0 Heegaard splitting. My question is: would adding 2 cells and 3 cells to the diagrams presented, would make them a 3-ball, hence the genus 0 Heegaard diagram?

Best,

Jorge.
[Heegaard diagrams of S^3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xx9FG.jpg)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.